# uitableview hiding 2 cells from scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

made a table view, and it does not make sense at all but my table view is hiding some cells.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 25;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil){
        cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    object= [self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=[object valueForKey:@"hLabel"];
    return cell;
}
```

It does render 25 cells but I am only able to view up to 23. 2 cells are hidden below. Though if I scroll further I can see them but if I leave the scroll the view comes back, 23rd being the last cell. Hence user is not able to select either 24 or 25.
Even if I reduce the cell count, lets say to 23, still the tableview is hiding 2 cells and I am not able to access them as the scroll ends at 2 cells prior.

Comment: is there any objects in your view other than tableview? If so set the tableview frame with code. height should be like (view height-tableview Yaxis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar issue and i don't know how but when i unchecked Autolayout, the issue gets resolved. Try turning off Autolayout. i hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 3):

I think your tableview height is more than screen height.
Decrease the height of the tableview (make it fit to view bound) and it will display all the cell.

And also check that this autoresizing constraint is setted in in the zib/storyboard for tableview.

[image]

Comment: I agree with you, but I don't think that `Decrease the height of the tableview` is a good fix. It would be preferable to set the frame in a `viewDidAppear` method or set constraints in a Interface Builder (depending the way the tableview is added in the view hierarchy).

Comment: @zbMax Yes, i am agree. You can see i have added constraint. and by means to decrease the size of tableview i means to set its frame to fit the view bound.

Comment: i reduced the size of my tableview and now its displaying fine. but I am not able to see any of those autosizing options. my options for table view end at origin settings. but the problem is solved so its all good.

Comment: So reducing size helped you or removing autolayout helped you?

Comment: both work but removing auto layout feels more appropriate solution.