# textView configured in IB of iOS 7 change font back to default font after the text property is changed programmatically

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitextview

**NOTE:**  The time when I asked this question was when Apple just released iOS 7. Apple reimplemented `UITextView` with `Text Kit` after iOS 7. `UITextView` had some bugs that time. The issue of this question was one of them. But now it's fixed.

---

There is a `UITextView` in my app which is configured in IB. The text view has some default text of which the font size is `60.0f`. The text view uses plain string to render text. If I change the text property of the text view programmatically when the app is running:

```
self.textView.text = @"some text different from default text";
```

the text view will change the font back to the default font.

configure font programmatically can solve this problem:

```
self.textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:60.0f];
```

This is a bug of the new `UITextView`.

Comment: Show us the code where you setting `hello , stackoverflow`

Comment: @Dilip it's almost same as the code I showed in this question. Only the string content is different, and without the font reconfiguring line.

Comment: than what is the problem i dont understand. `Hello, stackoverflow` has font size 18 which you set by the code and its correct. and `Hello World` has font size 60 which is set in the interface builder. So do you want the font size of your text view 60 or 18?

Comment: @Dilip ok, I will add the code that displayed picture3

Comment: Have you found the solution? I'm facing this problem too

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was a bug of `UITextView` when iOS 7 just released by Apple. It's fixed now

Answer (score 7):

It's strange behaviour appears when you uncheck Selectable in IB.
If you check Selectable, your Text View have got correct font.
You can add textView.selectable = NO in code if you don't want to select it

Comment: Is this a bug or an expected behaviour? Still happening to me in Xcode 6.2.

Answer (score 1):

Did u notice the T symbol in the right croner of font tab use this for set the font size
[image]

Comment: yeah, I know that. Does not work if I changed the content text in the run time.

Comment: so in case of runtime you should use some programmatic setting of fonts like you did previously

Comment: thank you. Do you mean that if I changed the content of a text view, I must reconfigure the font programmatically? That seems not right.

Comment: You Have an autoshrink property in file inspecter it is fixed font size by default change it it may work and check autolayout checkbox too

Comment: Where to set this "autoshrink property"? I did not find it in the file inspector. Because I will change the geometry of some views in the run time, I can not use autolayout. I've turned it off. But I don't think that is the problem though

Comment: Just see the screenshot added by me Autoshrink is there... if you need two fonts in two text in same textview then You should definitely have some programmatic settings...otherwise you should use 2 textfields

Comment: just checked. turning on auto layout in the file inspector does not solve my problem

Comment: man what version of xcode are you using? I can not find it in my xcode. I believe it is the Attribute Inspector in your screenshot. I double checked, there is no 'Autoshrink' field in my xcode. I am using xcode 5.02.

Comment: Please see this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996678/uitableview-hiding-2-cells-from-scroll/20996985#20996985 autosizing is another thing to check

Comment: thanks, I have read that question. As I mentioned before, auto layout is already turned off.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you set the font through IB and at runtime in viewdidload method programatically, then xcode will always pick the values set programatically.

To set the font programatically, use this :

```
[self.textview setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontname" size:128.0]];
```

Comment: thanks. I know how to set font programatically. But I want to set font in IB. In this question, I did not set font in `viewDidLoad` method. What I did is just changing the content text.

Comment: I tried the same thing at my end, and everything is working fine.

Comment: hmm.... strange... let me check it again. although I have checked several times....

Comment: Just delete the old textview and try using new textview.

Comment: Thanks for that! And for Swift Mac developers:         
textView.font = NSFont(name: "fontname", size: 18)

Answer (score 0):

If you change `self.textview.text` then you must set new font and size after that. Alternatively, in iOS7+ you can change `self.textview.attributedText` so that you can first obtain all attributes from previous text, and then change the text in `NSAttributedString` using one of its methods. After that, you change `self.textview.attributedText` with resulted attributed string. Doing so will reuse all the attributes you specified in IB.

Answer (score -2):

```
//  main.m
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"UIDisableLegacyTextView"];

    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

iOS7 textview has many bug.

this code is order to "use to iOS6 Textview" 
but this code is not apple officeial.